# Armature | Rig Smooth bends

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm using a Minecraft character rig which only has sharp bends. [image]

I'd like to change them so that there are smooth bends like in this rig:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do it by increasing the *Curved Bones segments number* or using the ***Spline IK*** bone constraint.
[image]

In the *Armature Data* header change the bone display type to ***B-Bone***. Then in the *Deform* panel of the *Bone header* increase the *segments* number for each bone. Play with *Ease In* and *Ease Out* values to control the smoothnes of a bend.
[image]