# Bend a mesh to L shape

Tags: mesh

How do I bend an 'I' shaped plane mesh to an 'L' shape with specific angle (say 80 degrees). Using deform seems to make a 'C' shape. Is there no simple way than creating bezier curves and such?

My mesh is 2D plane for now. I will add some depth to it eventually. Is it better to bend it before or after extrude?
Thanks.

Comment: Please research Shape Keys, and Armature. See which one is good for your first attempt. Then show your work so we can see what progress you make.  Try simple example of Shape Keys and Armature.

Comment: As atomicbezierslinger said you may use an armature and corrective shapekeys. Please see this example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82788/armature-rig-smooth-bends Give your object an armature and differ the segments number for each bone.

Comment: if you need to _animate_ the plane bending, or control it dynamically, just follow above advices, but your plane needs geometry where the bending occurs, otherwise you need to add it manually, eg: add an edge loop (ctrl-r) where it should bend precisely, then use that edge axis as rotation pivot in edit mode...

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use Simple Deform modifier with Restrictions - Limits. Set the first limit to 0.5, this will make the upper part vertical. And set the second limit from bigger than 0.5 to 1, this will change the shape of tail of L.

[image]
[image]